I want direct Vimeo file links (External IDs) for my videos
Vimeo offers direct file links to their pro users only. I want direct links to showcase work on my website. Here's the custom code for it:
<div data-poster-url="{{wf {&quot;path&quot;:&quot;cover-image&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;ImageRef&quot;\} }}" data-autoplay="true" data-loop="true" data-wf-ignore="true" class="project-covervideo w-background-video w-background-video-atom">

  <video id="" autoplay="" loop="" style="background-image:url(&quot;{{wf {&quot;path&quot;:&quot;cover-image&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;ImageRef&quot;\} }}&quot;)" muted="" playsinline="" data-wf-ignore="true" data-object-fit="cover">
    <source src="{{wf {&quot;path&quot;:&quot;vimeo-id&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;PlainText&quot;\} }}" data-wf-ignore="true">
  </video>

  <noscript>
    <img data-wf-bgvideo-fallback-img="true" src="{{wf {&quot;path&quot;:&quot;cover-image&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;ImageRef&quot;\} }}" alt=""/>
  </noscript>

</div>

The Url which is supported in the above code looks like: https://player.vimeo.com/progressive_redirect/playback/831507558/rendition/1080p/file.mp4?loc=external&signature=f4828b6619251e46ab4bcf5faf0fbc6eb1930b0f7a94f00859422d1e31fcc3a5
My video URL for which I'm trying to get a direct link like the above for is: https://vimeo.com/1005574390
I tried using postman to send an API request, I also tried searching for a similar link with Google inspect> by scanning the network section.
I do not have professional programming qualifications or know HTML or code. I'm just winging it using no code apps and trying to update my website.
